# Beep codes - 2 short; 4 long

Tags: post, boot

I'm getting these beep codes - (2 short, pause, 4 short, long pause) - repeating.

I couldn't find the meaning of these codes on the internet, the PC model is Omron NSA-CPU01-E.

Does anyone know what they could possibly mean?

Comment: Is that... a motherboard model... or something?

Comment: I am not finding any info on your computer, but beep codes are specific to motherboards.  Try to get some info off your motherboard (manufacturer, model number, etc.) so we have some more to go off of.

Answer (score 3):

Beep codes are BIOS specific. From what I can tell the Omron NSA-CPU01-E uses the Phoenix BIOS. Here is a link to a page explaining all the beep codes. You want the very last table explaining the Phoenix BIOS beep codes: http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Omron directly.
They make embedded systems for use in industrial environments.
I'm guessing [this](http://downloads.industrial.omron.eu/IAB/Products/Automation%20Systems/HMI/PC%20Based%20HMI/DyaloX%20Panel%20IPC/BRO_Dyalox/DyaloX_KPP_EN_INT03.pdf) is the type of PC you're referring to.
At the bottom of that PDF are the contact numbers / e-mail addresses for Omron worldwide.

**Edit:** Seeing as you're from Slovakia [Here](http://industrial.omron.eu/en/contact/omron_in_country/default.html?area=SK) are the contact details